# (osu!) (Question About Skinning) Editing Coloration/design of hitcircle without switching around overlay/hitcircle elements?

Tags: osu

I am currently working on a skin mix and am at the point where I am wanting to edit the hitcircle. The two skins I'm using for the hitcircle/hitcircle elements are:

https://www.reddit.com/r/OsuSkins/comments/bt3fdu/osuskin_n_o_e_l_v_5stdsdhd/ (Noel v5)

and

https://www.reddit.com/r/OsuSkins/comments/bfyxeo/overdrive_std/ (Overdrive)
What I am looking to do is keep the same exact shape and design of the Noel Skin but change the blue coloration to that of the overdrive skin. I have already tried switching around hitcircle and hitcircleoverlay elements but I can't get it to look how I want. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

I added this so it would make more since, sort of an example:

https://imgur.com/bnb7qp9

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remove the color of the hitcircle in a photo editing software by grayscaling it, and after that edit the skin's `skin.ini` file then locate the `[Colours]` section and remove everything but the `Combo1` one. Just apply the color you want here in the RGB format and you're done.

The code should look like this:

```
[Colours]
Combo1: 0,128,64
```

You can read on how the `skin.ini` works on the osu! wiki here: https://osu.ppy.sh/help/wiki/Skinning/skin.ini